# Unity 2D how to avoid my player moving over the enemies

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm doing a platformer and I have colliders and rigid bodies in my hero and my enemies. I have also colliders on my platforms.

Everything works and moves nice, dudes move along the platforms, they jump and they catch each other.

I use the collider in my enemies to discover if the hero touches them and then deal damage to the hero. And when slashing I use "overlapCicle" to discover if the sword touched the enemies.

My problem is that with this setup my hero and my enemies can walk one in the top of others. Additionally if I disable the collider of an enemy (to make it invulnerable for a second after being hit) it will fall through the platform..

What's the best approach to this structure of colliders?  I want everybody to walk over platforms. I want enemies colliders to detect the hero touching them and I want my sword (overlapcircle) to find enemies. And I want hero and enemies to be able to walk across each other, specially enemies.. they should not walk one over the others

Comment: Could you show the codes you have written so far?

Comment: this question is literally language independent ...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want the enemy and the player to be able to walk through each other, while being able to interact with each other.

In that case, you can create another physics layer for your interactions (attacking or vision detection), and set-up your Physics layers to ensure that the Player and Enemy do not collide, but their interaction layers  can collide with the respective characters.
Like so:

[image: Picture of Physics Layers setup]

Where `PlayerTriggers` and `EnemyTriggers` will be physics layer for interaction between the enemy/player.

This ensures that the enemy's vision/attack collider can hit the player, but the enemy itself can't do so. Vice versa.

To access the physics layer menu, go to `Edit` (Top left) and click on `Project Settings`.
You can read more about it in [Unity's Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html).